# what's the meaning of this line in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
 'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
```

what's the id="%1$s" and class="widget %2$s" meaning?

Comment: See here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar#Default_Usage and the `Notes` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such it doesn't mean much.

But I'm guessing this is used later with a function such as [**`sprintf()`**](http://fr.php.net/sprintf) -- in which case, those `%1$s` and `%2$s` are markers that indicate where strings will be injected into that one.

See the examples about **Argument swapping** on the `sprintf()` manual page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that those `%1`s are replaced later on with actual values; they're placeholders. Here's what I mean (in Python):

```
print 'One {0} three'.format('two')
```

The `{0}` (in your case `%1`) is replaced with `two`.